# Is there a way to have a static class name in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there a way to have a static class name in styled-components?

For example, in this demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-3tmvb?file=/index.js

when I inspect the `Title` styled-component, I see class `.cXxCPQ` that is having

```
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: palevioletred;
```

I like to have a custom class that has these css above.

```
.custom-class{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: palevioletred;
}
```

Is there a way we can do this?

Here is the whole code

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Wrapper from './Wrapper';
import Title from './Title';

// Render these styled components like normal react components.
// They will pass on all props and work
// like normal react components – except they're styled!
const App = () =>
  <Wrapper>
    <Title>Hello World, this is my first styled component!</Title>
  </Wrapper>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I was able to add a custom class part of it by doing this

```
    <Title className="custom-class">
      Hello World, this is my first styled component!
    </Title>
```

I see this on dom

```
<h1 class="custom-class sc-bwzfXH cXxCPQ">Hello World, this is my first styled component!</h1>
```

However, class that is used for applying css is not `custom-class` that I like to use.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by  "class that is used for applying css is not custom-class"?

Comment: See the `createGlobalStyle` helper to create styles that are not locally scoped: https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle

Comment: @LinDu What I mean by that is I see  the screenshot above using`.cXxCPQ` to apply css and I'm not seeing the `custom-class` class name that I added.

Comment: The entire idea of styled components is that the style has a different name for each component, to avoid possible conflicts of class names